# DefaultMessageListenerContainer multiple instances

Tags: java, spring, jms, javabeans

How can I have multiple instances of DefaultMessageListenerContainer created in runtime?

Now I have 2 beans:

```
@Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory, MQQueue mqQueue,
        MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter) {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        //read some properties and set to dmlc

        return defaultMessageListenerContainer;

}

@Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer2(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory, MQQueue mqQueue,
        MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter) {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        //read some properties and set to dmlc

        return defaultMessageListenerContainer;

}
```

And it works fine. But I want to have n instances of `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` depends on my properties file.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Which spring version are you using and why are you doing it like this?

Comment: Spring 4. I need to connect to multiple MQ.

Comment: Use `@JmsListener` and a `JmsListenerContainerFactory` per `ConnectionFactory`. Everything else will then be created.

Comment: Could you show sample code?

Comment: See the reference guide http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-annotated .